Cannot find module 'virtual:astro-icon'
Intento levantar un portafolio de manera local con el framework Astro, cuando intento acceder a una pantalla me arroja este error:

Cannot find module 'virtual:astro-icon' imported from 'C:/Users/emilio.quintero/Documents/GitHub/BlogMilio/node_modules/astro-icon/components/Icon.astro'

Instalé todas la dependecias, mire codigos con la misma estructura y todo parece estar bien.
Adjunto codigo que lo manda a llamar:
<div class="flex flex-wrap items-center gap-x-2">
    <p class="text-center">Encuentrame en</p>
    <ul class="flex flex-1 items-center gap-x-2 sm:flex-initial">
        {
            socialLinks.map(({ friendlyName, isWebmention, link, name }) => (
                <li class="flex">
                    <a
                        class="inline-block p-1 sm:hover:text-link"
                        href={link}
                        rel={`noopener noreferrer ${isWebmention ? "me authn" : ""}`}
                        target="_blank"
                    >
                        ***<Icon aria-hidden="true" class="h-6 w-6" focusable="false" name={name} />***
                        <span class="sr-only">{friendlyName}</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            ))
        }
    </ul>
</div>


Necesitas agregar el plugin para astro-icon
 npx astro add astro-icon

